# Using PreparedStament of JDBC with Mysql's TableName end with '\'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to insert something into my Mysql Database, which has a table whose name end with '`\`'. Its name is '`abc\`'.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection master = DriverManager.getConnection($URL,$USR,$PWD);
        String st = "insert into `abc\\` (`pad`,`c`,`k`,`id`) values(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = master.prepareStatement(st);
        pstmt.setInt(1, 10);
        pstmt.setInt(2, 1);
        pstmt.setString(3, "1");
        pstmt.setString(4, "2");
        pstmt.execute();
        master.close();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it doesn't work, the problem is :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

But, it the table's name is '`a\bc`', whose backslash is not the last character, my program works well.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "insert into "+'abc\`+" (`pad`,`c`,`k`,`id`) values(?,?,?,?)"; Try it!

Comment: try with escape character `'abc\\'` in your query string

Comment: That code won't even compile - please post a *real* short but complete example, that actually demonstrates the problem you describe.

Comment: @TSurendra Thanks for your response, but it doesn't work. This Exception : java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry and I have edited it to a complete example.

Comment: @Santhucool Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, did you make some typo?

Comment: @RobyCat I suggest you dont used / in your Table name. Make it abc!!

Comment: @Santhucool Yes I know it is bad but actually it is not my table but my client's , I have not right to change the name.

Comment: @RobyCat have you tried with `statement` query.

Answer (score 0):

It is working with `Statement`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,
            SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "password");
        String st = "insert into `abc\\` (`pad`,`c`,`k`,`d`) values(10,11,'5','6')";
        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(st);
        con.close();
}
```